# Alternative solution for printing pattern using python

Tags: python, string, design-patterns

I want to print pattern using python and i have done it but i want to 
know other solutions possible for the same:-

```
A B C D E F G F E D C B A
A B C D E F   F E D C B A
A B C D E       E D C B A
......
....
A                       A
```

and here is my code:-

```
n=0
for i in range(71,64,-1):
    for j in range(65,i+1):
        a=chr(j)
        print(a, end=" ")
    if n>0:
        for l in range(1,3+(n-1)*4):
            print(end=" ")
    if i<71:
        j=j+1
    for k in range(j-1,64,-1):
        b=chr(k)
        print(b, end=" ")
    n=n+1
    print()
```

Comment: People will tell you it's a bad idea to call a variable lowercase-l. Don't ask me why tho.

Comment: If you never use the variable, you can call it `_` instead.

Comment: One way could be to prepare the first line as a string and then print it, and then successively replace more and more in it with spaces for each line you print.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson you mean store the first line in a string variable then print it and for the next line remove the "G" letter with a space and print it again?

Comment: @rahulverma yes

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method using 3rd party library `numpy`. I use this library specifically because it allows vectorised assignment, which I use instead of an inner loop.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import numpy as np

n = 7

# extract first n letters from alphabet
letters = ascii_uppercase[:n]
res = np.array([list(letters + letters[-2::-1])] * (n-1))

# generate indices that are removed per line
idx = (range(n-i-1, n+i) for i in range(n-1))

# printing logic
print(' '.join(res[0]))
for i, j in enumerate(idx):
    # vectorised assignment
    res[i, j] = ' '
    print(' '.join(res[i]))
```

Result:

```
A B C D E F G F E D C B A
A B C D E F   F E D C B A
A B C D E       E D C B A
A B C D           D C B A
A B C               C B A
A B                   B A
A                       A
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do any of that complicated string range math. I wrote this in several minutes. Simple and easy to understand.

```
reversed_text = "ABCDEFG"[::-1]
reversed_text_length = len(reversed_text)

i = 0
while i < reversed_text_length:
    temp = ((" " * i) + reversed_text[i:])
    left = temp[::-1]
    right = temp[1:]
    line = (left + right)
    # line = " ".join([*(left + right)])
    print(line)
    i += 1
```

Result:

```
ABCDEFGFEDCBA
ABCDEF FEDCBA
ABCDE   EDCBA
ABCD     DCBA
ABC       CBA
AB         BA
A           A
```

If you swap the `line` comment, you get your result:

```
A B C D E F G F E D C B A
A B C D E F   F E D C B A
A B C D E       E D C B A
A B C D           D C B A
A B C               C B A
A B                   B A
A                       A
```